# Predicate Logic - Existential Elimination

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

I am working on a predicate logic proof given the following premises:

(For all x)(Fx > Vx)

(There exists x)(Fx & Bx)

Desired conclusion: (There exists) (Vx & Bx)

My instinct here says to use universal elimination on the first premise, generate Vx & Bx as a line, and then use existential introduction to finish it off. Any thoughts on how to approach this? I've done the following so far. Apologies for the poor formatting - I am assuming Fw in line 3.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Kevin Klement's [natural deduction proof editor and checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) here is one solution:

[image]

I started with a subproof for existential elimination and then within that subproof used universal elimination. This allowed me to choose the name, "w", in line 3 for existential elimination and use that same name in line 6 for universal elimination.

For more discussion see chapter 32 of [P. D. Magnus, Tim Button, J. Robert Loftis, Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach *forall x: Calgary Remix*](http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/).